# Polymorphism in Objective-C with Abstract Methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

I need to be able to reuse a ViewController in Objective-c.  In c# the code of what I'm trying to do would like like this:

```
 public abstract class SettingsViewController
{
    public abstract void SaveData();

    public void Save_Click()
    {
        SaveData();
    }
}

public class AgeController : SettingsViewController
{
    public override void SaveData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do Something from AgeController");
    }
}

public class GenderController : SettingsViewController
{
    public override void SaveData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do Something from GenderController");
    }
}
```

But I don't see any clear way how to do this.

Comment: just subclass and override; every method is virtual and dynamically bound in Objective-C. If you don't want a class to be instantiated explicitly throw exceptions from either its `init…` methods and/or every method you want subclasses to override.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Objective-C language, there are no abstract methods. But in Objective-C software development, you easily make a method abstract by implementing it with an NSAssert () as the code.

Comment: worked great.  a little wonky, but i guess everything seems that way coming from another language.  Thanks1

Answer (score 1):

You can use @protocol. Something like this:

```
@protocol KeeperP <NSObject>
@optional
  - (void)SaveData;
@end
```

Class SettingsViewController will be changed to:

```
 @interface SettingsViewController : NSObject <KeeperP>
 {
    - (void)Save_Click;
 }

 @implementation SettingsViewController
    - (void)Save_Click
    {
        [self SaveData];
    }
 @end
```

A compiler will not show warning if you will not override method

```
- (void)SaveData;
```

but if you call this method without overriding you will get a exception.

It is not abstract method but is very similar.

Comment: This is the most "Objective-C like" solution **in my opinion**. Rather than having to go through the trouble of implementing a base class that you are forbidden from using "as is" (...and having to setup defensive code just to enforce that), the protocol still provides the blueprint for each particular class, does not provide default implementations but forces the adopting concrete classes to do so themselves. Also, the whole of Cocoa/Cocoa Touch is designed around protocols one way or the other, so your code will feel more at home.

Comment: [continued] The solution with asserts is OK too, especially if the base class needs to provide default implementations for _some_ methods.